# Function returning an iterator of vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have this new class Seq that inherits vector and has some additional features. I can use all methods of vector with Seq.

Having this data structure:

```
Seq< vector<int> > sweepEvents;
```

I want to have a function that takes an element vector edge  search for it in `sweepEvents` and returns the iterator to the position of the found element in `sweepEvents` (if and only if `edge` is found) and the iterator to the last elements of the vector (if and only if `edge` is not found).

Then I want to work with this iterator, in that I want to compare the elements from the prev and the next position of iterator.

I have the following function for founding and returning the iterator:

```
Seq< vector<int> >::iterator QSweep::insertSweepEvents(edge_t edge,int currentDim){
    int changePosition;
    int found=0;

    for (int i=0;i<currentDim;i++){
         if (edge[0]==sweepEvents[i][1]){
             changePosition=i;
             found=1;
             return sweepEvents.begin()+changePosition;
         }
    }
    if (found==1){
        sweepEvents.rep().insert(sweepEvents.begin()+changePosition,edge);
        sweepEvents.rep().erase(sweepEvents.begin()+changePosition+1);
    }   
    else{
        sweepEvents.rep().insert(sweepEvents.end(),edge);
    }

    return sweepEvents.end()-1;
}
```

I then call this iterator in the main function. I actually tried but it does not compile and I do not know what syntax to use other than this:

```
int main(){
    Seq< vector<int> > sweepEvents;
    vector<int> edge;
    //.....initialize sweepEvents and edge

    //declare iterator but not working
     Seq< vector<int> >::iterator comparePosition; 

   //not working neither
    comparePosition=insertSweepEvents(edge,sweepEvents.size());
}
```

Any idea on how I should correctly call the iterator? I see it does not work as an integer index from an array?

Comment: what you mean "not working"? bad result, compiler error, core?

Comment: compiler error for definition of comparePosition and the assignment of comparePosition afterwards.

Comment: your if (found==1) block never gets executed, since you return when you set found = 1..

And what compiler errors do you get in which compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Is Seq< vector< T > >::iterator defined in your Seq class?

Making the parameter of the template 'vector' does not imply that exists the type Seq< vector< int > >::iterator

Answer (score 1):

What compilation error ? How is defined `Seq<X>::iterator` ?

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Seq
  : public std::vector<T>
{ };

typedef Seq< std::vector<int> > SeqI;

SeqI::iterator insertSweepEvents(SeqI &s)
{
  return s.begin();
}

int main()
{
  SeqI s;
  SeqI::iterator e = insertSweepEvents(s);
}
```

This works fine.

Comment: so SeqI is my datatype, so as parametr to my function I need the address of my sweepEvents list also?

Comment: No, but you need to work on a reference so the iterator you return is valid.

Comment: I am quite parallel with vectors I see.
So now that I have e (the iterator to the right position), how can I print the element at position e from s?or just the position?

Comment: You can use std::distance(v.begin(), it) to get the distance between two iterators (<iterator>)

Answer (score 0):

Something illogical in your code. See my comments:

```
int found = 0;
for (int i=0;i<currentDim;i++){
     if (edge[0]==sweepEvents[i][1]){
                 changePosition=i;
                 found=1; 
// This place is one, where we assign 1 to found, and we do return after that (maybe you want do break/?)
                 return sweepEvents.begin()+changePosition;
         }
}
if (found==1){ // as you see we reach this place only when found == 0
```

Comment: so I have no problem with founding what I want.
I supposed the element is not in the list!!.
Then I compare the new element with all elements iff I found one the same I say I found it and return the position.
Then if it is found I inserted in the right position if not at the end of my vector.

Comment: Maybe it is not main problem, but anyway you can remove this if block and leave only else. Also you can remove found variable.

Comment: if I remove found then the element that is found is added to the desired position and then also to the last position, as I tried it.

Comment: no you have return if element is found. and when we have reached if ( found ) - found will have 0 value, and if block will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

A little sidenote:

After a `vector` is changed, especially when appended to or inserted in, iterators to it become invalid.  That's due to the fact that the `vector` tries to allocate a minimally sized contiguous block of memory for it's internal data, while at the same time it tries to minimize the number of times it needs to allocate a new, bigger chunk.  So the data may move through memory, so iterators to it *before* a `push` are no longer valid *after* it.

Another little note:

You can find the difference between two iterators by using `std::difference( it1, it2 )`.  You can re-apply that difference by using `std::advance( it1, d )`.

A third little note:

You seem to have a 'return' statement inside the for-loop, but the rest of the code uses variables that are set only when returning...